# Postgresql duda campo numerico

Tags: sql, postgresql

Buenas necesito ingresar valores altos por ejemplo 65.000.00 para el precio de un producto tengo un campo Precio definido como Numeric(18.2) Pero solo me permite ingresar valores menores o iguales a 999.00 como haria en este caso?

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en otro lado. Sí se puede.

```
--PostgreSQL 9.6
--'\\' is a delimiter

select version() as postgresql_version;

create table grandes(
    el_valor numeric(18,2)
);

insert into grandes values (1234567899012345.79);

select * from grandes;
```

Quizás estés confundiendo puntos con comas. Podrías poner un ejemplo que no te funcione en un lugar como este: http://rextester.com/RVBJL23347

Comment: si tienes razon perdona el problema es cuando intento guardar esta cantidad por ejemplo 75.000.00

Comment: ¿No será un problema de puntuación? Porque si la cantidad es setenta y cinco mil se escribe en postgres así `75000.00` con un solo punto. En el ejemplo estoy insertando un número muchísimo más grande. ¿qué error te da? ¿pudiste probar con esa página que puse? (rextester.com)

Comment: lo que pasa es que estoy haciendo un sistema de ventas y ellos utilizan ese formato, hay alguna solucion para insertar esos valores altos como 50.000.000.00?

Comment: En principio no. Pero quizás el problema sea la configuración regional del equipo. Quizás sea bueno controlar el separador de decimales y el separador de miles en la configuración de números y de moneda. Y asegurarse que sea un valor distinto. Otra cosa. Recuerda votar las respuesta y comentarios que te sirvan, así le indicas al que te contesta que valoras sus respuesta (y quizás le das más ganas de continuar)